# SAS - Need to suppress this "data set limit reached" , when i set 0 outputs in my project

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

My client does not want to see intermediate work tables in SAS workflow and as a workaround, i have set option --> Results --> results general --> Maximum number of O/P data sets to add to the project AS 0.

Now, the issue is, i get this note for each of my program in workflow - "data set limit reached". Now i understand why, but can someone help me in suppressing it?? I do not want these notes to be generated in my workflow.

TBH, i am just using Proc SQl in my programs and creating tables out of it.

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: Are you using SAS Enterprise Guide?  If not, what do you mean by "workflow".

Comment: I added the [tag:enterprise-guide] tag, as that seems likely what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the only true solution here would be to use `PROC DATASETS` to clean up your intermediate data tables (which obviously is not ideal if you're testing).  In cases where I wanted to have a clean workflow, I did what you did and just lived with the notes.

Another possibility would be to use SAS Studio instead of Enterprise Guide.  If you have 3.7 (or possibly 3.6?) you have a workflow mode ("Visual") instead of just the "Programmer" mode which has only single programs; it's a much more simple version of the workflow than EG has, but that is somewhat of a benefit in some situations.

Comment: Exactly what I did in a similar scenario. After every program, I used proc datasets to remove any intermediate tables. Worked great.

Comment: @Joe- Yes, i am using EG and as i already confessed, i am more of proc SQL guy who is a newbie to SAS.. So, i added "Drop table" as my last step.  Thanks for the help!